AWS CodePipeline Session Policy Error on S3 ListBucket During Deploy
I am creating an AWS CodePipeline via a CloudFormation template with three steps

Checkout source from GitHub
Build using CodeBuild
Deploy

However, the pipeline fails on the Deploy step with the following message:
User: arn:aws:sts::AccountID:assumed-role/drive-tracker-cicd-prod-CodePipelineRole-QnWs78DD8pmv/1730118657170 is not authorized to perform: s3:ListBucket on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::drive-tracker-prod-artifacts" because no session policy allows the s3:ListBucket action (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: Z7135KF3QJY8W53J; S3 Extended Request ID: N+tgLvQdEVUmRhbMJBh+vPIP7X1W+sIVBwzZg8sEjqRgR3ZxHuxi2+QOjpBkkdLyb+hxBkZGQjU=; Proxy: null)

I verified via IAM PolicySimulator that both CodePipelineRole and CodeDeployRole are able to perform s3:ListBucket operation on the artifact storage bucket. Furthermore, I read that the error may be related to the role's inability to access KMS key which was used to encrypt the bucket si I added KMS permissions to both roles. Lastly, I verified that CodePipelineRole is able to assume CodeDeployRole. However, the error remained the same after each of these changes.
The pipeline definition:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: 'DriveTracker CI/CD pipeline'

Parameters:
  CodeStarArn:
    Type: String
  Branch:
    Type: String
  DeployStackName:
    Type: String

Resources:
  PipelineArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub "${DeployStackName}-artifacts"

  DriveTrackerPipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: drive-tracker-pipeline
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: CheckoutGithubSource
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeStarSourceConnection
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                ConnectionArn: !Ref CodeStarArn
                FullRepositoryId: "martinbalucha/DriveTracker"
                BranchName: !Ref Branch
              RunOrder: 1
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput

        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: BuildSolution
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: '1'
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref DriveTrackerBuild

        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: !Join [ "-", [ "Deploy", !Ref DeployStackName ] ]
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM
                OutputFileName: DeployResult
                StackName: !Ref DeployStackName
                TemplatePath: BuildOutput::deploy/application.yml
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CodeDeployRole.Arn
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              RunOrder: 1

  CodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodePipelineAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iam:PassRole
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetBucket
                  - s3:ListBucket
                Resource: 
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                      - /*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'codestar-connections:UseConnection'
                Resource: !Ref CodeStarArn
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codebuild:StartBuild
                  - codebuild:BatchGetBuilds                  
                Resource: !GetAtt DriveTrackerBuild.Arn
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - cloudformation:CreateStack
                  - cloudformation:DeleteStack
                  - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
                  - cloudformation:UpdateStack
                  - cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:SetStackPolicy
                  - cloudformation:ValidateTemplate
                  - sts:AssumeRole
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:*
                Resource: '*'

  DriveTrackerBuild:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${DeployStackName}-Build"
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: "buildspec.yml"
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: "aws/codebuild/standard:6.0"
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildServiceRole.Arn
      TimeoutInMinutes: 30
      QueuedTimeoutInMinutes: 60

  CodeBuildServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codebuild.amazonaws.com
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodeBuildPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject*
                  - s3:GetBucket*
                  - s3:ListBucket
                Resource: 
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                      - /*
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult
                  - codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: "*"
  
  CodeDeployRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                - !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
              Service: 
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodeDeployRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject*
                  - s3:GetBucket*
                  - s3:List*
                Resource: 
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                  - !Join
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                      - !Ref PipelineArtifactBucket
                      - /*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - cloudformation:CreateStack
                  - cloudformation:DeleteStack
                  - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
                  - cloudformation:UpdateStack
                  - cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet
                  - cloudformation:SetStackPolicy
                  - cloudformation:ValidateTemplate
                  - iam:PassRole
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:*
                Resource: '*'

Has anyone encountered this error before? What is the root cause of the issue and how do I remove it?
